# Mockito cast ActionForm to Class

Tags: java, testing, struts, mockito

I am having a problem with the following line of code:

```
OrderForm of = (OrderForm)form;
```

form is ActionForm and OrderForm is a class that extends ActionForm.

But I am trying to test this method and I don't how to do this.

For the reference, this is the method:

```
OrderForm of = (OrderForm)form;
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(getPublisherId(req)));
        of.setPublisherId( Integer.parseInt(getPublisherId(req)) );

        AdvertiserManager am = new AdvertiserManager();
        OrderManager om = new OrderManager();
        of = om.getOrder(of, Locale.getDefault());
        //If no valid campaign was found the id of 'of' is 0. So if id = 0 return 404 status.
        if (of.getId() == 0) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return null;
        }
```

METHOD signature:

```
public ActionForward performAction(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$3538880f cannot be cast to xxx.forms.orders.OrderForm
at xxx.IPOrderApiAction.performAction(IPOrderApiAction.java:82)
at xxx.IPOrderApiActionTest.testGetOrderApiCallNotExistingCampaignId(IPOrderApiActionTest.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Test:

```
private IPOrderApiAction spy;

@Test
public void testGetOrderApiCallNotExistingCampaignId() {
    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    ActionMapping mapping = mock(ActionMapping.class);
    ActionForm form = mock(ActionForm.class);
    OrderForm of = mock(OrderForm.class);
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("id", "1261");
    spy = Mockito.spy(new IPOrderApiAction());
    Mockito.doReturn("1").when((IPAuthenticatedAction)spy).getPublisherId(request);
    request.setParameters(map);
    when(mapping.getParameter()).thenReturn("getOrder");
    spy.performAction(mapping,form, request, response);
    assertEquals(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, response.getStatus());
}
```

It's struts 1.1

Comment: Any exceptions? Show the method signature please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing an instance of OrderForm to your method, but an instance of ActionForm:

```
ActionForm form = mock(ActionForm.class);
...
spy.performAction(mapping,form, request, response);
```

For the cast to succeed, the form must be an instance of OrderForm, so you need

```
ActionForm form = mock(OrderForm.class);
...
spy.performAction(mapping, form, request, response);
```